# SVG image export using R markdown

Tags: r, svg, knitr

I am creating a pdf report in Rstudio using Knitr. One of the requisites is that I generate all the plots as separate images apart from including them in the document. For that, I was using the following code:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
    echo = FALSE,
    message = FALSE,
    warning = FALSE,
    fig.align='center',
    fig.pos='H',
    fig.path = "plots/",
    dev = c("png"),
    dpi=500
)
```

Which worked just fine. Recently I've been asked to include vectorial images too. I thought adding "svg" to the dev outputs would do the trick, however though the image is generated it is always cropped. 
New code:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
    echo = FALSE,
    message = FALSE,
    warning = FALSE,
    fig.align='center',
    fig.pos='H',
    fig.path = "plots/",
    dev = c("png", "svg"),
    dpi=500
)
```

[Here](https://github.com/AndreaRP/Project_img/blob/master/prueba-1.png) you can see an example of png file, and [here](https://github.com/AndreaRP/Project_img/blob/master/prueba-1.svg) the corresponding svg image I am getting (you may have to check the xml code because the image viewer can't open it). I am new to vectorial images, but from what I know, a web browser should be able to open them, which is not the case. It looks like the XML generated by knitr is messed up somehow, but I have absolutely no idea how to fix it.

Update: OK, so by tinkering the XML code I discovered that the problem are the x and y coordinates in the image tag of the XML. For some reason they are set to  x="186" y="6".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg width="216" height="391">
  <image id="image0" width="216" height="391" x="186" y="6"
    xlink:href="blablabla..."/>
</svg>
```

I still have no idea how to fix this, as I don't know how to set them to 0 in the chunk settings.

The Rmd code I'm using is as follows, I only deleted all the boring text and used mtcars instead of the actual data:

````
---
title: "Title"
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    dev: pdf
    fig_caption: yes
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 3
documentclass: article
urlcolor: blue
classoption: a4paper
header-includes:
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage{float}
---

```{r setup, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, include=FALSE}
library("RColorBrewer")
library("pheatmap")
library("knitr")
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
    echo = FALSE,
    message = FALSE,
    warning = FALSE,
    fig.align='center',
    fig.pos='H',
    fig.path = "plots/",
    dev = c("png", "svg"),
    dpi=500
)

```

Some text here...                    

```{r prueba, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
hmcol <- rev(brewer.pal(11,"RdBu"))
pheatmap(  as.matrix(mtcars[1:20,1:6])
           , scale = "row"
           , cellwidth = 15
           , color = hmcol
           , border_color = NA
           , clustering_distance_cols = "correlation" 
           , clustering_distance_rows = "correlation" 
           , cluster_rows = T
           , cluster_cols = T
           , treeheight_row = 0
           , treeheight_col = 0
           , legend = TRUE
           , show_rownames = T
           , show_colnames = T
           , labels_col = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
          )
```
````

Comment: Works fine for me when kniting the RMD template using your chunk options. The SVG file is not cropped.

Comment: That's odd, if the default Rmd works, maybe some other thing in my document is causing the problem with the x and y coordinates? But I don't have any other graphical parameters specified...

Comment: Give us the code how you produced this plots ... this must be the source of the error.

Comment: I used pheatmap package to produce the heatmap, I've updated the question to include the code.